# How do I fill a PHP array with data from MySQL?

Tags: php

I'm using the Twilio API to send sms. I'm trying to change it so that I can send to a list of recipients from mysql results.

The example code given is:

```
$people = array(
    "+14155551212" => "First Lastname",
);
```

My code is:

```
$people = array(
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($usersphone)) {
    $people[$res['UserMobile']] = $res['UserFirstName'];
    }
);
```

The syntax is bad but I can't figure out where.

Comment: "Syntax is bad" -- why do you think it is?

Comment: That's not how `array()` works...  You can't embed a `while` loop in an `array` constructor.

Comment: You can't add a while loop into a array. change the first line to `$people = array();` and remove `);` at the end and that might help

Answer (score 0):

You can't put control structures into arrays.

```
$people = array();
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($usersphone)) {
    $people[$res["UserMobile"]] = $res["UserFirstName"];
};
```

Also, there's a ton of posts here on SO that will tell you all about not using the `mysql_*` functions anymore, since they're deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You have logic in your array definition.  You should define the array, and then populate it with the while.

```
// define the array
$people = array();
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($usersphone)) {
    // populate key with mobile and value with name
    $people[$res['UserMobile']] = $res['UserFirstName'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was confused about defining the array and populating it or incorporating the logic within it. Your answer helped me understand this.